# Suggesting the colours based on the background

Tags: machine-learning, prediction, recommendation-engine

What machine learning algorithm can be implemented to train a model that could suggest font colour based on the background colour?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to be even machine learning problem. Your "machine" don't learn anything from suggesting colours based on defined background colours.

I see this issue as :
1) Whether you have a set of pre-defined colours to pick up per each background color. Like your BG color is blue, then text color should be white, because it is good looking.

2) Or this might be crazy, but you can actually build the algorithm, where you give to your algorithm huge samples of examples of background color and some front color. So you would need treat this as a classification problem, and your model's response (Y) is the color in HEX format, and features (X) are the picture's aspects (brightness, dimness etc.)

Which model to choose - I can't tell you right now, but you would need to use popular methods, like choosing model with the lowest RMSE etc.

But again, your issue is a simple, and I'm not sure if you really need ML here.